# What does ServiceControllerServiceProvider even mean?

Tags: php, silex

As the famous quote goes two hardest problems in programming are parallelism and naming variables. I'm trying to understand all the DI contraptions in Silex and came across this class (http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/service_controller.html). I think I understand that it extends the service resolver so you can register a controller as a service but I can't make sense of the name esp. the first 'Service' part. Why is the 'Service' used twice here?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things at play here.

1. ServiceController (might as well be named __YOUR_NAME_HERE__Controller)
2. ServiceProvider (as described here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/providers)

It is basically a dependency injection for the ServiceController.
It provides you a ServiceController with all dependencies injected.

Might as well be called ServiceControllerFactory.

Naming is the hardest part of programming.